# How does one create a color array that includes opacity?

Tags: java, processing, sprite, rgba

I'm trying to create sprites in java using the Processing IDE (version 3.3.7). It works well except it is unable to draw transparent pixels due to my color[][] array only accepting colors in hexadecimal form and not rgba form.

```
void setup(){ //This chunk of code is working fine
  size(384, 216);
  surface.setResizable(true);
  noStroke();

  renderSprite(Sprite.test, 100, 100);
}

void renderSprite(color[][] tex, int x, int y){
  for(int i = 0; i < tex.length; i++){
    for(int k = 0; k < tex[i].length; k++){
      fill(tex[i][k]);
      rect(x + i, y + k, 1, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

The above part is not the problem, but may be useful in solving the problem.

```
static class Sprite{
  static color[][] test = new color[][]{
    {#FF0000, #00FF00},
    {#0000FF, #FFFFFF}
  };
}
```

This part is the problem. Using the (r, g, b, a) format in place of one of the hexadecimal values creates an error. (expecting RPAREN, found ',') I have tried creating a color object that uses rgba

```
static color nullPix = (0, 0, 0, 0);
```

to possibly replace one of the hex vales with but it gives me the same RPAREN error. (this does not happen when hexadecimal is used instead)

I am wondering why rgba cannot be used where hex can and if there are any possible solutions. rgb produces the same errors, so I don't think opacity itself is the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Processing provides a way to create images and specify per-pixel colour and transparency with its *PImage* objects.

In other words, you can scrap what you're trying to implement since it has been done already.

As an example, the following will create a red square of 50% opacity.

```
PImage sprite;

void setup() {
   .
   .
   .
    sprite = createImage(100, 100, ARGB);
    for (int i = 0; i < sprite.pixels.length; i++) {
        sprite.pixels[i] = color(255, 0, 0, 128);
    }
   .
   .
   .
}

void draw() {
   .
   .
   .
    image(sprite, 0, 0);
   .
   .
   .
}
```

This has the added advantage of caching the data so you needn't iterate over its pixels to draw the sprite every frame (unlike your *renderSprite()* method).